# How to connect to linux server using ssh with private key from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ssh, powershell-5.0

I have generated an ssh key pair using puttygen and can successfully connect to my CentOS server with my private key from putty on my Windows 10 workstation:

[image: image of successful connection to CentOS]

I want to connect to the server from Windows PowerShell and have loaded the Posh-SSH module with `Install-Module posh-ssh`

I have tried to create a new ssh session with:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$KeyFile = 'C:\Users\mark\Documents\ssh\privkey.ppk'
$sesh = New-SSHSession -ComputerName neon.localdomain -Credential $credential -Keyfile $KeyFile
```

I put in root and blank password for `Get-Credential` but I get this error:

> New-SSHSession : Invalid private key file.

I tried to convert the privkey file to a string by reading it and converting to base64 encoded but I get the same error:

```
$privkeyString = Get-Content $KeyFile
$Bytes = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($privkeyString))
$sesh = New-SSHSession -ComputerName neon.localdomain -Credential $credential -KeyString $Bytes
```

I also tried this but get the same error:

```
$sesh = New-SSHSession -ComputerName neon.localdomain -Credential $credential -KeyString $privkeystring
```

Any ideas on how to connect to a linux server using PowerShell with a private key file?

Comment: This question might be a good candidate for canonical answer on similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539007 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244250 .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`New-SSHSession` doesn't recognize PuTTY's key format (unfortunately neither the Gallery nor the project page mention this, but I found it in a [PowerShellMagazine article](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/03/posh-ssh-open-source-ssh-powershell-module/)). You need the private key in the OpenSSH format. You can [convert the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224066/1630171) with PuTTYgen:

1. Click *File → Load private key*.
2. Enter the passphrase if the key is password-protected.
3. Click *Conversions → Export OpenSSH key*.
4. Enter the filename for the exported key (do NOT overwrite the PPK file) and click *Save*.
5. Exit PuTTYgen.

Run `New-SSHSession` with the new key file:

```
$computer = 'neon.localdomain'
$username = 'foo'
$keyfile  = 'C:\path\to\priv_openssh.key'

$sess = New-SSHSession -Computer $computer -Credential $username -Keyfile $keyfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Same method can now be used as on Linux.

ssh username@domain.com -p 22 -i C:\Users\user.ssh\private_key_id_rsa

Answer (score -1):

![enter image descrcontent://com

google.android

.apps.docs.storage

/document/ac=1 ;doc=encoded

=fsqjpfgiD4T3A RrffzMZw4PTYZT

6QpUPYqwksyw V+GU9 7GS B8X /YTY4WiUiption here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMNpU.png)

Comment: This formatting is broken... what are you trying to say?

Comment: Please edit your answer and correct the formatting.